# Fetching all the records inside a particular attribute in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

In this example i have an array named "nameArray" which holds five objects-{A,B,C,D,E}. In Core Data i have an entity named "Details" and an attribute "name". I have saved the "nameArray" inside the core database. After that i have used NSFetchRequest to fetch all the data stored inside "name" attribute. The code i have used is below:

```
_nameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E", nil];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
Details *userDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext];
for (NSString*name1 in _nameArray)
{
    userDetails.name = name1;
}
NSError *error;
[appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext save:&error];
if (error==nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Data is saved");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Data not saved and error is %@",error);
}

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Details"];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self manage]
NSArray *results = [appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSLog(@"The result array is %@",results);
if (results.count>0)
{
    NSManagedObject *name1 = (NSManagedObject *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"The name is %@",[name1 valueForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

The problem is that i am not able to fetch all the records stored inside the "name" attribute. The "results" array is giving only one object, i.e. the last object 'E' as output. I need to output all the data stored inside the "name" attribute. The "results" array output is below:-

> The result array is (
>       " (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000040000  ; data: )",
>       " (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: {\n    name = E;\n    number = 0;\n})"
>   )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inserted one object into CoreData and keep updating that object. You need to move the line

```
Details *userDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext];
```

into the for loop as follows

```
for (NSString*name1 in _nameArray)
{
    Details *userDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext];
    userDetails.name = name1;
}
```

And if you want to see all the inserted objects

```
NSArray *results = [appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
if (results.count>0)
{
    for (NSManagedObject*userDetails in results)
    {
      NSLog(@"The name is %@",[userDetails valueForKey:@"name"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following method to fetch all records for a particular entity.

In your case pass nil to predicate

```
+(NSArray*)getAllObjectsForEntityName:(NSString*)entityName WithPredicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate{


    AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;


    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:entityName];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if(predicate)
       [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *results = [appDel.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (error != nil) {

        //Deal with failure
    }
    else {

        //Deal with success
    }
    return results;
}
```

and to save data inside core data you have to update your code

```
_nameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E", nil];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

for (NSString*name1 in _nameArray)
{
Details *userDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext];
    userDetails.name = name1;
}
```

Comment: I followed the method as suggested by you but it is not working.

Comment: Because when you insert an object you are over writing the previous one, insertNewObjectForEntityForName should be inside the loop